# Exposed Dropdown Menu in Forms Flutter

Tags: forms, flutter, drop-down-menu, textfield

I'm implementing a basic Dropdown menu in a form but not getting the expected UI. I'm wanting something like this,
[image]

But what I'm getting is something like
[this](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/e640e0522edecb81d7957409e9277cde9728adade05a4929bcbbf46f4acfb3af8478f9d0146d55e5baa53ed53f82f14925dedd7add889137d4c5e1a1e1180a51)
.
My code,

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                    items: genderList
                        .map((String value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value, child: Text(value)))
                        .toList(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'State',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        initGenderValue = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: wrap DropdownButtonFormField with the SizedBox and set width as you expected

Comment: You only want the dropdownMenu to be displayed below the Button? I have achieved something similiar [here](https://i.imgur.com/Xp3fQkU.png), but I had to vendor and modify the default dropdown in flutter. If this is what you are after I could share the changes

Comment: Yeah i want something like that. The menus are right below the field so that the field is also visible.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and here it is how I achieved it. After going through several portals, I could figure it out myself.

All we need to use is 'labelText' within 'decoration' attribute.

```
DropdownButtonFormField(decoration: const InputDecoration(
hintText: 'Established Year',
labelText: 'Established Year',
border: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide:
      BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.Green),
),), items: const [
DropdownMenuItem(
  value: 'Option 1',
  child: Text('Option 1'),
),
DropdownMenuItem(
  value: 'Option 2',
  child: Text('Option 2'),
),],  onChanged: (value) {
setState(() {});},)
```

Here is the output:

[image]